# Reducing the width of ion-select (Ionic v3)

Tags: ionic-framework

I want an `ion-select` and `ion-input`  in same line with width as follows:

```
ion-select 10% width

ion-input 10% width
```

I wrote the following code for that ([Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-5rwrte?file=pages%2Ftabs%2Ftabs.html)):

```
  <div style="display: flex">
      <ion-item style="width:10%">
        <ion-label>+2</ion-label>
        <ion-select>
          <ion-option value="1">+1</ion-option>
          <ion-option value="2">+2</ion-option>
          <ion-option value="3">+3</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item  style="width:90%">
        <ion-input [value]="23321312321"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>

  </div>
```

But unfortunately, upon doing so text of ion-select disappears.

[image]

How do I achive this.

Comment: if you need to show ion-select text then you need to increase width. I suggest you to use ion-grid. If you need to show ion-select text as well as selected text then you need to give width 50%

Answer (score 0):

You can use **width / max-width** property to set your **ion-item** width to 10%. what you need to add is **!important** as ion-item already have its default style so to overwrite style we need to make our style **important**.

> max-width: 10% !important;
>
> width: 10% !important;

Please check below code:

```
<div style="display: flex">
      <ion-item style="max-width: 14% !important;">
        <!-- <ion-label>+2</ion-label> -->
        <ion-select style="max-width: 100% !important;">
          <ion-option value="1">+1</ion-option>
          <ion-option value="2">+2</ion-option>
          <ion-option value="3">+3</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-item  style="max-width: 84% !important;">
        <ion-input [value]="23321312321"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>

  </div>

  <div>hello</div>
```

Adjust your **Ion-item** width as per your requirement.

Hope this will helps.

Comment: This does not work. https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-heffmg?file=pages/tabs/tabs.html

Comment: Please check my updated answer I have modify my answer.